# GIT reset branch and delete all changes after merge

Tags: git

I had two branches, the main one and a feature branch. After changing something in the main branch (I know now, that's bad practice. I found out the best practice for changes and I'll do it by the book next time) I merged the main branch into the feature branch.

The merge went bad, so I reset the branch back to the last commit before the merge. This went well. Only problem is, if I want to commit any new changes, the merge gets included again.

I tried rebasing the branch, I wasn't successful.

I just want to completely delete the merge and get back to the last commit, Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hope is by now you've figured out you shouldn't develop directly on the main branch. You should take the following steps:

1. Reset your main branch to before the merge
2. Rebase your feature branch on top of main branch
3. Make your changes in the feature branch, commit and what not
4. Go to main branch and merge feature branch into it

Comment: I actually don't want to merge, but to unmerge and delete all changes, so I'd have the feature branch and the main branch separated again.

Comment: i thought you reset the branch. make sure you did a hard reset not a soft one.

Comment: Yeah, I did. But every time I try to push a new commit, the merge gets included again. I still see the merge in the history, although I reset the branch to the last working commit. I should mention I use an application to manage my repositories (Git Extensions) and not using the command line (although I tried the branch reset with the command line too)

Comment: So before you push the commit what's the status? When you do `git status` what files do you see there?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command `git merge --abort` if you don't want to merge it because of conflicts.